# Compute the DE $\frac{d^2 \theta(\tau)}{d \tau^2} = \alpha (1 - \pi \sin \tau) \tan(\Omega t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

So basically I have to compute this DE (which comes from a problem that I am working on),

$$ \frac{d^2 \theta(\tau)}{d \tau^2} = \alpha (1 - \pi \sin \tau) \tan(\Omega t), $$ where $\alpha$ is a real constant, $\tau \equiv \omega t$; and $\Omega \ll \omega$. Also $\theta(0) = 0 = \frac{d \theta}{d \tau} \bigg|_{\tau = 0}$.

Can someone help me with doing this problem?

> My work: I tried writing the $\tan$ term as $\tan \left(\frac \Omega \omega \tau \right)$ and expanding $\tan (\dots)$ to its first term, as $\frac \Omega \omega \ll 1$. But this approach is wrong as $\tau$ is a fast time scale and will go on increasing.

Comment: Numerically or analytically?

Comment: Analytically will be a better bet.

Comment: Can you use the [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)? I'm not actually sure if it works for arguments of trig functions other than $x$ though i.e $\frac{\Omega x}{\omega}$

Comment: Thanks will try. In the meantime can you please see if anything else works for it?

Comment: Mathematica gives $\theta'$ in terms of Beta functions and it's impossible to get $\theta$ in closed form. Try to approximate with power series